# sympyのUnionの中のInterval範囲の個数は、いくつになりますか？

Tags: python, sympy

①sympyのUnionの中のInterval範囲の個数は、いくつになりますか？
②これでいいですか。「Union→Interval→Union」をしてみました。
よろしくお願いします。

```
from sympy import *
k = Symbol('k')
ineq = 'k**2-40>0'
ans1=solve_univariate_inequality(sympify(ineq), k, relational=False)
print('#',ineq,':',ans1)
my_Union0=list(ans1.args[0:1])[0]
my_Union1=list(ans1.args[1:2])[0]
print('# my_Union0 :',my_Union0)
print('# my_Union1 :',my_Union1)
ans2=my_Union0.union(my_Union1)
print('# 元に戻す  :',ans2)
# k**2-40>0 : Union(Interval.open(-oo, -2*sqrt(10)), Interval.open(2*sqrt(10), oo))
# my_Union0 : Interval.open(-oo, -2*sqrt(10))
# my_Union1 : Interval.open(2*sqrt(10), oo)
# 元に戻す　 : Union(Interval.open(-oo, -2*sqrt(10)), Interval.open(2*sqrt(10), oo)
```

Comment: 結論部分だけではなくて、その疑問に至るまでの経緯を書くようにしてみてください。私はこの質問文だけを読んでも、何の個数を聞かれていて、どうなると期待通りなのかがよく分かりませんでした。

Answer (score -2):

Unionの中のIntervalが2個以上ならカウントできていると,多分思います。
問題①Intervalが,1個の時？
問題②pythonのループの使い方を教えて下さい。
追加の質問よろしくお願いします。

(参考)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60917259/sympy-get-constituent-subsets-from-union

```
from sympy import *
k = Symbol('k')
ineq = 'k**2-40>0'
my_Union=solve_univariate_inequality(sympify(ineq), k, relational=False)
print('#',my_Union)
n=0
total_list = []
for subset in my_Union.args:
    n=n+1
    total_list.append(subset)

for i in range(n):
    # print(i)
    if i==0:
       my_Union2=total_list[i]
    else:
       my_Union2=my_Union2+total_list[i]
print('#',my_Union2)
print('#',n)
# Union(Interval.open(-oo, -2*sqrt(10)), Interval.open(2*sqrt(10), oo))
# Union(Interval.open(-oo, -2*sqrt(10)), Interval.open(2*sqrt(10), oo))
# 2
```

Comment: こちらは自身の質問に対する回答なのか、それとも追加の疑問なのかが一見すると分かりづらいように感じます。